# MDX - icCube - How can i make i filter by Date to an Histogram

Tags: mdx, iccube

This is the source code in my Histogram

```
SELECT { NonEmpty([Measures].[vente_total_produit]),[Measures].[Date_Construction_Produit] }*{ @{produitv![Produit].[Produit]} } ON COLUMNS,
       { NonEmpty( Order( [TimeProduit].[TimeProduit].[Année].allmembers Measures].[Date_Construction_Produit], BASC),[Measures][Date_Construction_Produit]) } ON ROWS 
  FROM ( SELECT { @{date![TimeProduit]. [TimeProduit].[Jour]} } ON 0 FROM [CubeVente2])
  where{Tail([Statvente].[Statvente].[statVente])}
```

When there is a date , it's work fine but the problem is
When i select a non existed date in the datePicker it shows this error:

All series on a given axis must be on the same data type

Is there a way to resolve this error? Txs, Marwen.

Comment: Looks like you're getting an empty results (you can check from the monitoring tab). If this is the case it's a known issue that has been fixed in dev and will be part of the coming release

Comment: Yes, it's an empty result, I have in my report a Pie Chart and a Google Combo, When I select a non existed date in the datePicker the Pie Chart disappeared but the Google Combo show me this error.

Answer (score 0):

Should be fixed in the coming release 5.1.8+